# Can't create new project in Ruby on Rails

Tags: rvm, ruby-on-rails-2

After insatlling rails through rvm, when i create new project

rails new project_name

creats project with name "new" not with "project_name", but folder contain all project files,
after that i try to start server with command

rails server or rails s

instead of the starting server, create folder "server" or "s" with project files.

ruby 1.8.7
rails 2.3.14
I need this version of ruby and rails.

OS Ubuntu 11.10

What i must to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For rails versions before 3.0 the rails command is used only for creating a new application

```
rails APP_NAME
```

Then you use script/server to run the dev server

In newer versions of rails you use the rails command to do many things like create app, run server, etc...

If you are creating a new app you would be better off on ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.1

If you need to run 2.3 - better invest in a good book that targets that version

Answer (score 0):

## How to fix your problem without upgrading rails (not recommended)

I think you are using rails 3.x.x commands. In rails 2.3, creating a new project goes like this:

```
rails project_name
```

And then running the server goes like this:

```
script/server
```

This will make it work.

## How to fix your problem by upgrading rails

I think **you should definitely start any new project with the latest version of Rails**. As of 28th of october the latest version is Rails 3.1.1. So you may need to run the following:

```
gem install rails
```